# What is `set` definition? AKA what does `set` do?

Tags: python, set

I just finished LearnPythonTheHardWay as my intro to programming and set my mind on a sudoku related project. I've been reading through the code of a Sudoku Generator that was uploaded [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578250-sudoku-game-generator/) 
to learn some things, and I ran into the line `available = set(range(1,10))`. I read that as `available = set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])` but I'm not sure what `set` is.

I tried googling `python set`, looked through the code to see if `set` had been defined anywhere, and now I'm coming to you.

Thanks.

Comment: Google [harder](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)

Comment: Relevant [meta SO post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260743/how-to-handle-questions-that-have-answers-in-the-languages-documentation) on what to do about questions with answers in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Set is built-in type. [From the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set):

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects. Common uses include membership testing, removing duplicates from a sequence, and computing mathematical operations such as intersection, union, difference, and symmetric difference.

Answer (score 0):

A `set` in Python is the collection used to mimic the mathematical notion of [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)). To put it very succinctly, a set is a list of unique objects, that is, *it **cannot** contain duplicates*, which a `list` can do.

Answer (score 0):

to make it easy to understand ,
lets take a list ,

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,7,9]
print list(set(a))
```

the output will be ,

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9]
```

You can prevent repetitive number using set.
For more usage of set you have to refer to the docs.
Thanks to my friend here who reminded me about the lack of order , 
Incase if the list 'a' was like,

```
a =[7,7,5,5,5,1,2,3,4,6,9]
print list(set(a))
```

will still print the output as

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9]
```

You cant preserve order in set.

Comment: A very important aspect in the definition of a set is the lack of order.

Comment: will really appreciate your comment if there is an explanation , which is easy to understand unlike the answers that are posted in this page.

Comment: A [hash](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-hashable) is a function that turns an immutable object into some number and sets store a hash of your elements. This implementation allows faster look-up times, but allows no duplicate elements (the hash would be the same) or ordering.

Answer (score 0):

A set is kind of like an unordered list, with unique elements. Documentation exists though, so I'm not sure why you couldn't find it:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set

Comment: "a set is kind of like an unordered list". Are you implying a `list` is then ordered by definition?

Comment: In Python, the elements of a list are in the same order as you pass them in. E.g. `[3,1]` is a 3, followed by a 1. However, set([3,1]) is just defined as "a 3 and a 1" with no particular order. In fact, on my machine, `str(set([3, 1]))` evaluates to `'set([1, 3])'`, with the order reversed.

Comment: I got ordering confused with sorting, sorry. In terms of ordering, I fully agree. I guess I need some more coffee :)